# JS controls the text length according to the window width

Tags: javascript, dom

Responsive page:

1. When the window size is less than 500px, cut off the text.
2. When the window size is greater than 500px, the text returns to its
   normal length.

I have completed the first point. I can’t figure out the second point. When the window is smaller than 500px, the text has been cut off. When the window is larger than 500px, how to restore the text to the normal length?

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.con');

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  items.forEach(element => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 500)
      element.innerText = truncateText(element, 100);
  });

});

function truncateText(element, maxLength) {
  let truncated = element.innerText;
  if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
    truncated = truncated.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';
  }
  return truncated;
}
```

My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/niuuin/76L1pszu/10/

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Instead of doing in JS, this can be done by using `@media`  and `line-clamp` in css

Comment: @DhanaD. I'll try it,thank you for help:)

Comment: Besides line clamp, you can use `text-ellipsis` in CSS too. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: I have edited your fiddle if you want to see what I have done. https://jsfiddle.net/7yb84dq0/2/

Comment: @DhanaD. `line-clamp` Solved my problem perfectly,thanks:) https://jsfiddle.net/niuuin/1z69k7gy/15/

Comment: @HelloWorld.exe This is also a good method, but this method does not set the number of lines, `line-clamp` is a good method, thank you very much for your help :)